# radio button display in middle of label

Tags: html, css

This html needs to display the radio icon to the left of the label but it is above it.
Chrome (left image), firefox 45.0.1 (right image)

[image]

The reason I nested the input in the label because the code needs to make the label clickable "clicking the label activate the radio button as well"

How can I get it to display correctly in all browsers? Thanks

```
.radio-label {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio-label">
      <input type="radio" name={{group}} checked={{value}} value={{name}}>{{caption}}
    </label>
```

Comment: can you share a screenshot

Comment: Are you able to see the image I included in the post?

Comment: Try float: left ? For radio button

Comment: What if you put the input outside the label and associate them using the for attribute? It will behave the same but may render correctly. Without a more complete code listing (or ideally sample) is hard to diagnose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<label class="radio-label">
  <input type="radio" name={{group}} checked={{value}} value={{name}}>
  <div>{{caption}}</div>
</label>
```

and styling like this...

```css
.radio-label {
    width: 200px; // you can modify this as per your needs...
}
.radio-label, .radio-label input {
    float: left;
}

.radio-label div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`display:inline-block` property doesn't mean that you are forcing element to come on left it just means you want element in single line. Use float left which actually mean to left align a element

```
.radio-inline {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not realise that the bootstrap styling was affecting it, which I do not want so I removed and edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You just try with,

```
.radio-inline {
 float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pack both in a div and then align one item to left and other on right i.e radio button to left and label to right.
give a specific width to outer div and give 50% to each item

Comment: That will not make the label clickable to toggle the radio button so you have to click on the button itself which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: so you have to write label click function that will make the radio checked.